# How can binding expressions/named parameters be used when following the multi-output pattern for dotnet-isolated Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, .net-5

**In .net 3.x** I have an azure function that generates thumbnails whenever a user uploads a new profile image.  It uses a QueueTrigger, a Blob Input Binding (imageToProcess) and Blob Output Bindings for each thumbnail size. With .net 3.1 my azure function (which works great) is defined like this:

```
    public async static Task RunAsync(
    [QueueTrigger("%ProfileImageQueueName%", Connection = "ProfileImageQueueConnectionString")]ImageToProcess imageToProcess,
    [Blob("profileimagestmp/{FullImagePath}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob originalImageTmp,
    [Blob("profileimages/{RelativePath}profileImage-24.png", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob image24),
    [Blob("profileimages/{RelativePath}profileImage-40.png", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")] CloudBlockBlob image40)
```

In the code above, "RelativePath" is a property on the queue message "ImageToProcess" that determines the path structure for the original blob.  It also determines the path structure for the output blobs (through binding expressions).

**With .net 5 (dotnet-isolated)** I understand that having multiple outputs is done very differently.

I am attempting to follow the Multiple Output Bindings pattern when implementing a .net 5 (dotnet-isolated) Azure Function as shown in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide

With .net 5, my azure function is defined like this:

```
    public async Task<FunctionOutput> Run(
    [QueueTrigger("%ProfileImageQueueName%", Connection = "ProfileImageQueueConnectionString")] string imageToProcessString,
    [BlobInput("profileimagestmp/{FullImagePath}", Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")] byte[] originalImageTmp)
```

It returns the "MultiOutput" like this:

```
    return new MultiOutput(imageToProcess.RelativePath)
    {
        Image24 = thumbnail24.
        Image40 = thumbnail40
    };
```

My "MultiOuput" class looks like this:

```
    public class MultiOutput
    {
        public MultiOutput(string relativePath)
        {
            RelativePath = relativePath;
        }

        public string RelativePath { get; set; }

        [BlobOutput("profileimages/{RelativePath}profileImage-original.png", Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")]
        public string OriginalImage { get; set; }

        [BlobOutput("profileimages/{RelativePath}profileImage-24.png", Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")]
        public string Image24 { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run the function I am getting the following exception: "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'RelativePath'."

To try and get around this issue I added a "RelativePath" property on my MultiOutput class that I set in it's constructor.  The error persists.

My question is this, how do you use binding expressions in a Multiple Output scenario with .net 5 Azure Functions?

Comment: You may want to ask on the azure-functions-dotnet-worker repo. A quick grok of the code looks very different from the 3.1 code and doesn't look to support this kind of "complex" reference https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker

Comment: Thanks.  I reached out to one of the team members and he says binding expressions are supported but I haven't seen any examples yet with multi output.

Comment: Well if u find the answer, make sure to self-answer your question. Good luck to you

Comment: Have you tried to use `{FullImagePath}` instead; because the input binding creates a binding expression named `FullImagePath`. 

```
[BlobOutput("profileimages/{FullImagePath}profileImage-original.png", Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")]
public string OriginalImage { get; set; }

[BlobOutput("profileimages/{RelativePath}profileImage-24.png", Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")]
public string Image24 { get; set; }
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#trigger-file-name

Comment: @WillyTjandra - FullImagePath is not the correct value.  It is actually how the RelativePath is generated inside of the ImageToProcess class.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @NapoleonIkeJones - No.  I entered this issue but my project changed directions so I didn't have the time to create a repo for them: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/430